# CGI Script writing security

Tags: python, security, cgi

I know that CGI programs sometimes run as the Apache user. I also know that for a CGI program to write to a data file, you can make the file world-writable. However, this means it can be written to (or even deleted) by other users who have a logon to the server or an attacker could install their own CGI programs there.

What I am asking is there a more secure way to allow a script to write to a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The rationale: separate CGI  folders and Data folders

Usually, `cgi` scripts are stored in a *separate* folder (usually `cgi`) that is *not* world-writable. Only privileged users (who are supposed to create the `cgi` scripts) have write-access to this folder.

*Other* files are stored *another* folder, where permissions are more lenient.
Making it world-writable isn't a great idea either, though. Only the user(s) with a reason to access the folder should be able to access it.

---

## Marking folders as containg CGI scripts in Apache:

### ScriptAlias

The `ScriptAlias` directive allows Apache to know whether a given folder is meant to contain `cgi` scripts that should be executed:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/
```

Would let Apache execute all files in those folders, expecting those to be `cgi` files.

### ExecCGI

You can give Apache permission to execute `cgi` scripts in a specific folder using the `ExecCGI` `Option`:

```
<Directory /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/somedir>
    Options +ExecCGI
</Directory>
```

You will then also need to indicate how a `cgi` script can be differentiated from another file, which is done using [the `AddHandler` Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addhandler). Using:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
```

Would indicate that `cgi` scripts have the extension `.cgi`

### More info

You should have a look at the [Apache documentation regarding CGI script execution](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html).